# Aggregate data from kafka topic and upload it in the new topic

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

```
val jsonSchema = StructType(Array(
    StructField("event_type", StringType),
    StructField("category", StringType),
    StructField("item_id", StringType),
    StructField("item_price", IntegerType),
    StructField("uid", StringType),
    StructField("timestamp", LongType)
))
```

I have a kafka topic with json value represented in scheme above. I need to put agg data by hour from the earliest timestamp i have to another kafka topic. I know that i need to use update method with window, but i dont understand how to do it in the right way

I'm assuming that i want to stream like this

```
val newData = spark
    .readStream
    .format("kafka")
    .options(kafkaParams)
    .load
    .select(from_json($"value".cast("string"), jsonSchema).alias("value"))
```

But i dont really understand how to transform that into new value with json like this:

```
{"start_ts":1577865600,"end_ts":1577869200,"revenue": sum of item_price,"visitors": count of uids},
{"start_ts":1577869200,"end_ts":1577872800,"revenue":sum of item_price,"visitors":count of uids},
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
val parseddf = newData
    .select('value.cast("string"))
    .withColumn("value",from_json(col("value"),jsonSchema))
    .select(col("value.*"))
    .withColumn("timestamp", from_unixtime($"timestamp"/1000).cast(TimestampType))

val uData = parseddf
    .withWatermark("timestamp", "60 minutes")
    .na.fill("undefined")
    .withColumn("uid", when($"uid" === "undefined", 0).otherwise(1))
    .groupBy(window($"timestamp", "60 minutes"))
    .agg(sum("item_price")) as("revenue"), sum("uid") as("visitors"))
    .withColumn("start_ts", unix_timestamp($"window.start"))
    .withColumn("end_ts", unix_timestamp($"window.end"))
    .withColumn("value", to_json(struct($"start_ts", $"end_ts", $"revenue", $"visitors")))
    .drop("window", "revenue", "visitors", "start_ts", "end_ts")
    .writeStream
    .outputMode("update")
    .format("kafka")
    .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("10 seconds"))
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "$server")
    .option("checkpointLocation", s"$checkpoint")
    .option("topic", s"$kafka_topic")
    .start()
```